# Manipulate the following equation for $P_2$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

> I am trying to manipulate Equation 5 to find $P_2$. Equation 5 as well as my work so far is shown below. I am unsure as to how I should isolate $P_2$ from here, although I suspect I should be writing each side as an exponent of $e$, or something like that. Any hints or advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Change the signs and take the exponential of both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ln(P_2)=(\frac{\Delta H}{R})(\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2}) + ln(P_1)$$

$$P_2 = e^{(\frac{\Delta H}{R})(\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2}) + ln(P_1)}$$

$$P_2 = e^{(\frac{\Delta H}{R})(\frac{1}{T_1} - \frac{1}{T_2})} \times e^{ln(P_1)}$$

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.